# Does Windows 10's BitLocker need special hardware support?

Tags: windows, windows-10, encryption, bitlocker

Does Windows 10's BitLocker need special hardware support or can I expect it to work in any computer (such as Mac Book Pro)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bitlocker normally requires the computer to have a [TPM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trusted_Platform_Module) (Trusted Platform Module) chip. Apple has not shipped a computer with TPM since 2006.

It is possible to work around the lack of a TPM chip by setting a Group Policy of *Allow BitLocker without a compatible TPM* under *Administrative Templates -> Windows Components -> BitLocker Drive Encryption -> Operating System Drives*. Step by step instructions for that are [here](http://www.digitalcitizen.life/how-enable-bitlocker-without-tpm-chip-windows-7-windows-8)

Comment: This is technically correct, but for the record, apparently, you can't just use BitLocker and FileVault at the same time due to number of partitions.

Comment: Here's the question I really have: http://superuser.com/questions/997363/is-it-possible-to-have-bitlocker-and-filevault-on-the-same-macboock-pro-with-mac