# Is it possible to have BitLocker and FileVault on the same MacBoock Pro with Mac OS X Yosemite or El Capitan and Windows 10?

Tags: macos, windows-10, boot-camp, bitlocker, filevault

Is it possible to have BitLocker and FileVault on the same MacBook Pro with Mac OS X Yosemite or El Capitan and Windows 10?

So far I only found this technique: http://joeraff.org/20131010/how-to-use-both-filevault2-and-bitlocker-simultaneously-on-a-dual-boot-mac-running-bootcamp/ wich is from 2013, so knowing wether it works on newer versions would be good. Or maybe another technique.

Answer (score 2):

My Macbook Pro 13 inch with retina early 2015 model is configured for both filevault 2 and Windows 10 enterprise with bitlocker enabled.

I did a lot of reading and found a couple of guides, one was the one you listed.  I think from memory it missed a step needed in El Cap about new security to allow the partition to be created.

I had to boot into osx recovery and run csrutil disable to allow the partition software to run correctly